# Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate: Unable to locate persister

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to work with entity inside request method of Spring boot application. The entity is in another project and my pom.xml has dependencies for it. Why I get this error message?:

org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.ric.bill.model.bs.Par

```
package com.ric.web;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.management.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.management.CacheStatistics;

import org.hibernate.stat.Statistics;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.ric.bill.BillServ;
import com.ric.bill.Calc;
import com.ric.bill.ChrgServ;
import com.ric.bill.excp.ErrorWhileChrg;
import com.ric.bill.model.ar.House;
import com.ric.bill.model.ar.Kart;
import com.ric.bill.model.ar.Kw;
import com.ric.bill.model.bs.Par;

@RestController
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.ric.bill")
public class GreetingController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private BillServ billServ;

    @Autowired
    private ChrgServ chrgServ;

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="lsk", defaultValue="00000000") String lsk) {

        Par par = em.find(Par.class, 64); <---Error hapens here

...
```

my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="localEntity">
        <description>Spring JPA Demo with LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="localContainerEntity">
        <description>Spring JPA Demo with LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

BillWebApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BillWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BillWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JPAConfigTwo.java (got from examples)

```
package com.ric.web;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfigTwo {  
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransMan(){
        JpaTransactionManager jtManager = new JpaTransactionManager(
                getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return jtManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lcemfb.setPackagesToScan("com.ric.bill");
        lcemfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        lcemfb.setPersistenceUnitName("localContainerEntity");
        LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
        lcemfb.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
        return lcemfb;
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
           BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
           dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
           dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:DB");
           dataSource.setUsername("lkk");
           dataSource.setPassword("1111");
           return dataSource;
    }
}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ric.billWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>billWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BillWeb</name>
    <description>Web services for billing</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <!--    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.ric.check</groupId>
          <artifactId>HibernateEHCacheExample</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>    -->

         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
          <artifactId>Billing</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
          <exclusion> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion> 
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>  -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2.2.21</version>
        </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

full error stack:

```
2016-08-08 20:09:39.172  INFO 39376 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-08 20:09:39.188  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-08 20:09:39.189  INFO 39376 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-08-08 20:09:39.321  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-08 20:09:39.321  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2706 ms
2016-08-08 20:09:39.522  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.524  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.527  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.527  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.528  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.528  INFO 39376 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.665  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager  : Found explicit default unit with name 'localContainerEntity' in persistence.xml - overriding local default unit settings ('packagesToScan'/'mappingResources')
2016-08-08 20:09:39.676  INFO 39376 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'localContainerEntity'
2016-08-08 20:09:39.677  WARN 39376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence   : HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
2016-08-08 20:09:39.686  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: localContainerEntity
    ...]
2016-08-08 20:09:39.784  INFO 39376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
2016-08-08 20:09:39.786  INFO 39376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-08 20:09:39.788  INFO 39376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-08 20:09:39.841  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-08-08 20:09:40.392  INFO 39376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2016-08-08 20:09:41.079  INFO 39376 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'localContainerEntity'
2016-08-08 20:09:42.318  INFO 39376 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1bb5a082: startup date [Mon Aug 08 20:09:36 NOVT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-08 20:09:42.523  INFO 39376 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public com.ric.web.Greeting com.ric.web.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
2016-08-08 20:09:42.531  INFO 39376 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-08-08 20:09:42.533  INFO 39376 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-08-08 20:09:42.624  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-08 20:09:42.625  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-08 20:09:42.731  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-08 20:09:43.547  INFO 39376 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-08 20:09:43.677  INFO 39376 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-08 20:09:43.685  INFO 39376 --- [           main] com.ric.web.BillWebApplication           : Started BillWebApplication in 7.566 seconds (JVM running for 8.208)
2016-08-08 20:09:46.550  INFO 39376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-08 20:09:46.551  INFO 39376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-08 20:09:46.594  INFO 39376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 43 ms
2016-08-08 20:09:46.919 ERROR 39376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: com.ric.bill.model.bs.Par] with root cause

org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.ric.bill.model.bs.Par
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:792) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2882) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2662) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2648) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1105) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ric.web.GreetingController.greeting(GreetingController.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ric.web.GreetingController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d8c8815e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ric.web.GreetingController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$136cf73d.greeting(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Comment: Did you fix this error? Did you modify the model class before you got this error?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was exactly what Lev says ("ensures all your subpackage annotated classes are scanned properly"), just move the class who runs your application to root.

```
---  com.app <----(your main class here)
----- com.app.rest
----- com.app.dao
----- com.app.dto
-----    ...
```

Aditionaly I added the Scan base, like this:

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.app" })

Answer (score -2):

I found next information about this problem:
It is recommended by Spring Boot to run your application from the root package and all your entities, controllers,DAO's and other service classes should be placed in child packages. This is not a hard and fast rule but it ensures all your subpackage annotated classes are scanned properly.

Also I read next article about proper placement of classes in Spring Boot project: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Eventually I combined both project into single. I think this is not great solution for this problem, but it helped me.